# hoverevent on qwtplot in Qt

Tags: qt, hover, qwt

I have a qwtplot with a couple of qwtplotcurves attached to it. I want to have an event triggered when I hover one of the curves. I understood that I have to use installeventfilter() for this, but on what object should I use this? I cant use it on plot curve since this is not an object.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the `event_filter` which comes with Qwt. You should use the class `CanvasPicker` (it is not part of the Qwt API, but you'll find the code in the examples).
You can instantiate it in your class using

```
    picker = new CanvasPicker(plot); // plot is a pointer to your instance of QwtPlot
```

You'll see that the event filter you refer to is installed in the constructor of `CanvasPicker`.

Now have a look at CanvasPicker::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *e) which is called when an event occurs in the event loop of `QwtPlot`. Implement your application logic in the switch construct, f.i. change `case QEvent::MouseMove:`.